# Guard for RoR not detecting file changes or updates in Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, guard

I have a RoR 3.2.5 app with the guard gem installed to automatically run MiniTest::Spec tests. The guardfile is configured correctly to run specs automatically - I know this because I've tested Guard on the same app on my Mac OS X environment and it automatically runs spec tests when the files that are watched by Guard are changed.

However, under my Windows (8 Release Preview) environment, Guard does not run tests automatically when files are changed (and these are same files changed in the same way under my Mac env). However, tests do run in Guard if I hit 'enter' or type 'minitest'.

Has anyone else run into the same issue? Should I just give up trying to make Guard work properly under Windows?

Thanks

Comment: Rails on windows is such a dodgy proposition that it's a wonder when things work at all. Maybe windows 8 is better though, I'd be interested to hear your experience.

Comment: I'm finding guard is not noticing file changes for my Windows 7 install either, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Nah - in the end I've been working on the OSX side of my machine to get Guard to work properly... and have pretty much switched to dev'ing exclusively on OSX rather than Windows.

And with Rails on Windows, I've not had really any issues getting it going - used the RailsInstaller... it's just this Guard issue that's been a bit of a roadblock.